# Passing double pointer inside a function recursive

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to pass a double pointer in recursive function which realloc this size. This is the function:

```
int main(){
    PERSONA *tablaHash = (PERSONA *) malloc(1 * sizeof(PERSONA));
     redimensionar(&tablaHash, regToInput, 1, "TypeA", 1);
    return 0;
};

int redimensionar(PERSONA **tablaHash, PERSONA reg, int tam, int tipoPruebaColision, int n) {
    if (n < 15) {
        n *= 2;
        *tablaHash = realloc( *tablaHash, (n*tam) * sizeof(PERSONA) );
        return ( redimensionar(tablaHash, reg, n*tam, tipoPruebaColision, n) ); //HERE IS THE ERROR
    }
    else {
        insertar(*tablaHash, reg, tam, tipoPruebaColision);
        return (tam);
    }
}
```

This function no reallocate good the memory (process is fine, error is in recursive call). I have tryed this function and it is working fine:

```
int redimensionar(PERSONA **tablaHash, PERSONA reg, int tam, int tipoPruebaColision, int n) {
        n *= 2;
        *tablaHash = realloc( *tablaHash, (n*tam) * sizeof(PERSONA) );
        insertar(*tablaHash, reg, tam, tipoPruebaColision);
}
```

So memory reallocation is fine, the problem is passing the double pointer to recursive function. Any idea how should be passed?

The question is: How pass a double pointer to a recursive function for working fine? First entry is fine, recursives entries no, so pointer is not passing fine in the recursion.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read [mcve], that very important for people to make a quick and accurate answer.

Comment: `insertar(tablaHash...)`

Comment: Also: you're not using `realloc` quite correctly...

Comment: How are you creating the pointer? And how are you calling the function?

Comment: Please don't change the code after comments. Just post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I have updated code showing how I create the pointer and call the function

Comment: In `redimensionar(&tablaHash, regToInput, 1, "TypeA", 1);`  fourth argument is "string" but your function is not supposed to receive string in fourth argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 iterations, `tam` becomes so large it overflows and becomes `0`:

```
1. n = 2, tam = 1
2. n = 4, tam = 2
3. n = 8, tam = 8
4. n = 16, tam = 64
5. n = 32, tam = 1024
6. n = 64, tam = 32768
7. n = 128, tam = 2097152
8. n = 256, tam = 268435456
9. n = 512, tam = 0
```

Because of this, you try to allocate `0` bytes and `realloc` returns NULL. You should always check to see if `malloc()/realloc()` return NULL.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked that, never return null. The problem is, apparently, realloc is not realloc parent variable, only local variable, but I have passed parent variable by reference and I am updating its value... So I do not know what is happening

Comment: @JuMoGar With fewer iterations, it works fine in my test: https://ideone.com/ZqRzlB ....Wait, do you realize, than `realloc()` can leave the pointer unchanged but still be successful?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have saw the problem with this answer. It was a little fault in parent variable